# PhpStorm Code Sniffer only show first 100 errors

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

How can I extend this number, because I have a 5000 lines of code where it has 8000 errors (known from command line `phpcs`), but it can show only first 100 in PhpStorm?!

Comment: I think if your code has that many errors, you're probably not at the stage where you need to worry about seeing all them.

Comment: As far as I'm aware it is limited for performance reasons (as such analysis is run after 1 sec or so delay when you edit your file -- you simply do not need to see that many errors at that stage +  it takes some time to simply list those errors). You can try to run CodeSniffer inspection alone -- it may not have that limit applied there: `Code | Run Inspection by Name...`

Comment: It doesn't detect the opened file and when I check whole project I get 77k error... CodeIgniter.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a fix for this? I tried searching the PHPStorm Registry for a value that may tweak the max number, but wasn't able to find one. Did you?

Comment: Left it in the state of undiscovered issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer so can do this in setting.
[image]